# Issue in LabelEncoder fit_transform() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm getting the following error when trying to execute the following code.

```
class LabelOneHotEncoder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ohe = OneHotEncoder()
        self.le = LabelEncoder()
    def fit_transform(self, x):
        features = self.le.fit_transform( x)
        return self.ohe.fit_transform( features.reshape(-1,1))
    def transform( self, x):
        return self.ohe.transform( self.le.transform( x.reshape(-1,1)))
    def inverse_tranform( self, x):
        return self.le.inverse_transform( self.ohe.inverse_tranform( x))
    def inverse_labels( self, x):
        return self.le.inverse_transform( x)

y = list(map(ImageToLabelDict.get, train_images))
lohe = LabelOneHotEncoder()
y_cat = lohe.fit_transform(y)
```

Error

```
perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: The error seems to be from your data. Are you sure your data have valid values and no `None` or `null` or `NA` values in it?

Comment: Yes. Error was with the data path. I was using a windows machine for the training and when defining the path the following was missing. Original : df["Image"] = df["Image"].map(lambda x: "train/"+x) Update : df["Image"] = df["Image"].map(lambda x: "train\\"+x)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very confusing...

So many variables are missing.

I guess it might happen at `ar`. The `ar` generated by `LabelOneHotEncoder` may have some `np.NaN` values. I might happen when you put the `data` which need to be transformed into a model which doesn't have some feature/values.

```
One word: your training data is bigger than the transformed data.
```